# RSA SecurId HTTPS redirect just shows "redirect"

Tags: https, redirection, iis, rsa

We have set up a site on IIS8 using RSA SecurID.  We have clicked "Redirect HTTP Connections to Secure Server" and "Require Secure Connection to Access Protected Pages".  However, when we go to http://oursite.com/ it simply shows "redirect" (literally, the HTML is 
`<html><body>redirect</body></html>`
)

We do have a redirect rule on the site as well, but this does not seem to have an effect, enabled or disabled, on this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.